# How do I set up an FTP connection?

Tags: iphone, ftp

I am trying to setup an FTP connection using iPhone-iPad(Simulator)/Xcode. Up to this point I discovered I need to use the CFFTP API, but I have had no success.

I have browsed the net and ended up by following what seemed the most clear to me, that is :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html
and :
The O'Reilly site :
.....oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html

But even though, it seemed relatively clear at first view. I still haven't been able to make a working connection. Meaning download or upload a sample file.

One question I have for start : Is this possible on the Simulator ?

Another question is :
It seems that my callback function is not called in the code I wrote by putting together the information I got from the two documents mentioned above.
What are the possible reasons for this to happen ?

If you know about some sample code or tutorial showing the steps necessary to build an FTP connection and check that it works please let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing code, it's difficult to comment on what could be causing a problem in your specific application.

I highly recommend looking at Apple's sample application [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) as a basis for building an application that uses FTP.

Comment: Thanks for this tip about SimpleFTPSample this is the kind of indication I needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip about SimpleFTPSample, this is the kind of indication I needed. Nevertheless I still have a few problems to solve before it (SimpleFTPSample) works. After changing the setting from iPhone Device 4.0 (missing in my case) to Simulator 3.2 I get the message : "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSStreamDelegate'". Any idea where to go from this point ?

Comment: @Michel - NSStreamDelegate was added as an informal protocol in iOS 4.0, but the methods for it have been present since 2.0.  You should safely be able to set your base SDK to 4.2 and your deployment target to 3.x to build this sample and have it work on older OS versions.

Comment: Brad, thanks for your tips. But I must be missing some important points. For my SDK, I see only : iPhone Device 4.0 (missing), iPhone Device 3.2 and iPhone Simulator 3.2; I have no 4.2. Since I am working on the simulator I tried iPhone Simulator 3.2, but I get the errors I mentioned. And if I try some other settings I also get errors. Another detail I noticed : the call to the method CFReadStreamSetClient seems central in the documents I mentioned in my first post and I see no such a call in the SimpleFTP example.

Comment: @Michel - You don't have the latest iOS SDK installed on your system.  You need to download the 4.2 SDK that has been available since November.  As far as the use of CFReadStreamSetClient, the SimpleFTPSample appears to use the higher level NSStream class and not the lower CFNetwork APIs.  There's more than one way to accomplish the same task here.

Comment: I see. I think you are referring to the Beta version of the new XCode. I must say that since I am a beginner as an iOS developper I was rather reluctant to use a Beta version, thinking it was a bit looking for trouble. But I might have to change my mind if I want to do what I need.

Comment: In order to make my question more concrete, I rewrote it under this title : How do I FTP on the iPhone ?

Comment: @Michel - No, the latest stable iOS SDK is version 4.2, and has been since November.  I'm not using the beta either.

Comment: OK, thanks. I followed your advice and installed the latest SDK. Nevertheless I still get the message : "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSStreamDelegate'".

Comment: @Michel - Set the Base SDK to either iOS 4.2 or Latest iOS, and then set your target's Deployment Target to whatever the minimum OS version that you want to support.  This will have it build with the 4.x SDK, which contains a definition for this protocol.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I finally got over this problem and now it compiles fine. I am still not able to perform an ftp download though. When I try to download something from my own ftp site it briefly displays the message "Receiving" and then "Connection failed" or "Stream open error". On the other hand I have been able to perform an upload, which is of course a good news for me.