# Counting number of files at a URL in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to count the number of files contained in a folder URL in XCode, to be able to know how many images I want to obtain and how many buttons I need to create in my screen.

I have found some information about counting files in your offline directory, but have no idea how to do it for a URL.

Here is an example that works for offline:

```
int numberOfFileInFolder = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Angry"] error:Nil] count];
```

I would like to do the same thing, but for a URL such as @"http://hello/images/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in a simple way.
One solution would be to connect to that folder using FTP ( [How do I set up an FTP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805998/855738) ), and then retrieve the list of files inside of it ( [Download FTP directory contents to ios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10407238/855738) )

The other solution that I used when I ran into the same problem as you was to download an xml (or whatever you like) with a list of the files in the folder. Such an xml file would be quite easy to generate using a scripted page, for example do something like http://hello/images/folder_listing.php which would serve you the xml. Of course, this would mean for you to have access to that server

If you're really, really, really lucky, it just might happen that accessing http://hello/images would return a simple html page with a list of all the object inside the folder, something that Apache does sometimes automatically, in which case you would be able to do some sort of parsing to the html source of the page.

Either way, you're in for quite some work, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. I was expecting something like this.. 
I have access to the server. 
Keeping that in mind, is there a simple way to download and read a txt file that could contain the file count for each directory?

Comment: @Julien  That text file would have to be generated by the server.  So if you can modify the server code, then you could potentially have the server generate the information you want on the fly.  Basically you would be creating a web service that counts files for the specific URL and return that info as JSON formatted data.  For example calling up `http://hello/images/count` could trigger a server script that counted the files in `images` and returned the JSON data

Comment: Here's a quick solution, for a php script: http://pastebin.com/7z4PfwrF A php file with this code placed inside a directory should return the file listing. I didn't got the chance to test the code, but it should be ok. Short disclaimer: the find_all_files function is not made by me, I found it on php.net, but it's very simple and amazing

Comment: @BBog: I know it's a bit late in the day but your linked script was a great help to me, thanks.